# Poisson process arrival time.

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, poisson-process

let  $N_t$ be the Poisson process with parameter $\lambda$ and $S_{n}$ denote the time of the $n^{th}$ event. define $T_i:=S_i-S_{i-1}$

find $E(S_{4}|N(1)=2)$.

---

on the one hand, use the method in [post 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2974012/conditional-poisson-process-time-of-nth-event), think of the Poisson process $\tilde{N}$ restart at time $1$(the corresponding arrival time is $\tilde{S}$):
$$E(S_{4}|N(1)=2)=1+E(S_{4}-1|N(1)=2)=1+E(\tilde{S}_{2}|N(1)=2)=1+E(\tilde{S}_{2})=1+\frac{2}{\lambda}$$

---

on the other hand, I want to solve this problem directly:
$$E(S_{4}|N(1)=2)=E(S_{2}|N(1)=2)+E(T_3|N(1)=2)+E(T_4|N(1)=2):=A+B+C$$

use the method in [post 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1963006/calculate-et-kn-t-k-t-k-the-arrival-times-of-n-t), $f_{(S_1,S_2)|N}(s_1,s_2)=2$, then $f_{S_2|N}(x)=2x$, hence $A=2/3$

use independence we get $B=C=\frac{1}{\lambda}$, then $E(S_{4}|N(1)=2)=\frac{2}{3}+\frac{2}{\lambda}$

---

but result does not consistent. what's wrong? I think perhaps $T_3$ is not independent of $N(1)=2$?

$N(1)=2$ is euivalent to $S_2\le 1, S_3>1$,  so
$$B=E[T_3|N(1)=2]=E[T_3|T_1+T_2\le 1,T_1+T_2+T_3>1]\overset{*}{=}E[T_3|T_3>1-T_1-T_2]\overset{\text{memoryless}}{=}=1-T_1-T_2+E[T_3]$$

does * holds? how to make these two result consistent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> does * holds?

The short answer is that $E[T_3 \mid T_1+T_2\le 1,\, T_1+T_2+T_3>1]\overset{*}{=}E[T_3 \mid T_3 > 1-T_1-T_2]$ is true but not helpful in the way you'd like.

You might think that by definition $T_3 > 0$ such that the new expression of conditioning on the right hand side $T_3 > 1-T_1-T_2$ automatically takes care of $T_1$ and $T_2$.

Unfortunately, while the equal sign $\overset{*}{=}$ is technically true in terms of the symbolic algebraic manipulation, when it comes to calculation you still have to make the implicit $T_1 + T_2 < 1$ explicit.

The next equal sign $E[T_3 \mid T_3>1-T_1-T_2]\overset{\text{memoryless}}{=}1-T_1-T_2+E[T_3]$ is sloppy at best, and it should be interpreted as false most of the time.

If we are talking about $t_1$ and $t_2$ as two constants, then $E[T_3 \mid T_3 > 1 -t_1 - t_2] = 1 - t_1 - t_2 + E[T_3]$ is true.

Alternatively, if we are taking the expectation with respect to only $T_3$ then
$E_{T_3}[T_3 \mid T_3>1-T_1-T_2] = 1 - T_1 - T_2 + E[T_3]$ is also true, while the right hand side is still a function of the random variables $T_1$ and $T_2$. One still has to further take the expectation $E_{T_1,T_2}[\text{blah}]$.

> how to make these two result consistent?

The decomposition $E(S_{4} \mid N(1)=2) =  \ldots =A+B+C$ is correct and one indeed can "solve it directly". It's just that one has to actually do some calculations for $B$ (or quote additional known results like what's done for $A$ and $C$).

The $A = \frac23$ and $C = \frac1{\lambda}$ are correct, and your hunch that "$T_3$ is not independent of $N(1) = 2$" is also correct.

Following your notation that $S_2 = T_1 + T_2$, I shall use the dummy variable $s$ for $S_2$ and $t$ for $t_3$ in their respective marginal densities $f_{S_2}(s)$ and $f_{T_3}(t)$. We know that $f_{S_2}$ is a Gamma distribution with shape parameter $2$ and $f_{T_3}$ is exponential.

For both generality and clarity, I shall use $\tau$ to denote the given cutoff time length, as in here we have $\tau = 1$ and we are conditioning on $N(\tau) = 2$.

$$B := E\bigr( T_3 ~\big|~ N(\tau) = 2 \bigr) = \frac{ \iint_{\Omega} t \cdot f_{S_2,T_3}(s,t) \,\mathrm{d}t \,\mathrm{d}s }{ \Pr\{  N(\tau) = 2 \} } $$

where the joint density $f_{S_2,T_3}$ is the direct product of the marginals $f_{S_2}$ and $f_{T_3}$ because all $T_i$ are mutually independent. The 2-dim integral is over the region $\Omega = \{ (t,s): 0 < s < \tau,~t > \tau - s \}$. Lastly, the denominator $\Pr\{  N(\tau) = 2 \}$ is just familiar probability mass function of the discrete Poisson distribution

$$\Pr\{  N(\tau) = k \} = e^{ -\lambda \tau } \frac{ (\lambda \tau)^k }{ k! } $$

Evaluating the integral is just routine work (but by no means allowing any shortcut without actual calculation).
\begin{align}
\iint_{\Omega} t \cdot f_{S_2,T_3}(s,t) \,\mathrm{d}t \,\mathrm{d}s  &= \int_{s = 0}^{ \tau } \int_{t = \tau - s}^{\infty} t \cdot f_{S_2}(s) \cdot f_{T_3}(t)\,\mathrm{d}t \,\mathrm{d}s \\
&= \int_{s = 0}^{ \tau } \int_{t = \tau - s}^{\infty} t \cdot \frac{ \lambda }{ \Gamma(2) } (\lambda s)^{2-1} e^{-\lambda s} \cdot \lambda e^{-\lambda t} \,\mathrm{d}t \,\mathrm{d}s \\
&= \int_{s = 0}^{ \tau } \frac{ \lambda }{ \Gamma(2) } \lambda s e^{-\lambda s} \left[ \int_{t = \tau - s}^{\infty} t \cdot \lambda e^{-\lambda t} \,\mathrm{d}t \right] \,\mathrm{d}s \\
&= \int_{s = 0}^{ \tau } \frac{ \lambda }{ \Gamma(2) } \lambda s e^{-\lambda s} \left[ \left( \tau - s + \frac1{ \lambda} \right) e^{-\lambda (\tau - s)} \,\mathrm{d}t \right] \,\mathrm{d}s \\
&= e^{ -\lambda \tau } \int_{s = 0}^{ \tau } \frac{ \lambda }{ \Gamma(2) } \lambda s \left( \bigl(\tau + \frac1{ \lambda} \bigr) - s\right)\,\mathrm{d}s \\
&= e^{ -\lambda \tau } \left( \bigl(\tau + \frac1{ \lambda} \bigr) \frac{ (\lambda \tau)^2 }2 - \frac1{\lambda} \frac{ (\lambda \tau)^3 }3 \right) \qquad \text{, then with}~\tau = 1 \\
& = e^{-\lambda} \frac{ \lambda^2}2 \left( 1 + \frac1{ \lambda} - \frac23 \right)
\end{align}
Put things back together
$$B = \frac{ \iint_{\Omega} t \cdot f_{S_2,T_3}(s,t) \,\mathrm{d}t \,\mathrm{d}s }{ \Pr\{  N(\tau) = 2 \} }  = \frac{ e^{-\lambda} \frac{ \lambda^2}2 \left( 1 + \frac1{ \lambda} - \frac23 \right) }{ e^{-\lambda} \frac{ \lambda^2}2 } = 1 + \frac1{ \lambda} - \frac23 \\
E[T_3] = A + B + C = \frac23 + \left( 1 + \frac1{ \lambda} - \frac23 \right) + \frac1{ \lambda} = 1 + \frac2{ \lambda}$$
So you see, the decomposition into $S_2 + T_3 + T_4$ is not a "natural cutting". Conditioning on $N(1) = 2$ we have a $T_3$ that really should be split into two parts (as remarked by Julien Berestycki in his answer), one part goes together nicely with $S_2$ and the other with $T_4$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you answer! Can you elaborate how to split $T_3$ into 2 parts? I don't understand why $T_3$ has the same law as $[T_3 -1]+[1-T_2]$ in Julien Berestycki's answer. Any reference would also be appreciated!

Comment: Several points: (1) I'm afraid I cannot provide you with a reference because this is part of the basic consequences that is often left as an exercise (exactly how you encountered this problem). (2) I acknowledged Julien's answer out of courtesy, and you should NOT read my answer and his "together" because his notation doesn't follow yours (while mine does) and is unintentionally inconsistent. Julien's $T_3$  is the same as yours while his $T_2$  is your $S_2$ , which is btw the same as $T_2$  in that [post 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1963006) you linked yourself.

Comment: (3) The expression $[T_3 - 1] + [1 - T_2]$ is just a shorthand for talking about the distribution (density) when there's a split in the region (at time $\tau = 1$), and is by no means the arithmetic between random variables like in e.g. your $S_2 = T_1 + T_2$. (4) That expression is "sloppy" in that the conditioning on $N(\tau) = 2$ is there when you "need it" and is not there when you don't.

Comment: Okay, so the $[T_3 - 1]$ part is just restarting at time $\tau = 1$, exactly what you did for $S_4 | N(\tau) = 2  \to \tilde{S}_2$. The latter part $[1 - T_2]$ where $T_2$ is the arrival time (NOT inter-arrival time) ... so it should be $[1 - S_2]$ in  your notation ... is saying the same thing as, again, that [post 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1963006) you linked: conditioning on $N_{\tau}$ gives you the order statistics of uniform. If you're merely quoting the result of that post and do not understand what it is saying, it's totally okay, but please realize that ....

Comment: ...this also means there are plenty of other basics stuff you need to know (that is not necessarily needed for your original exercise). Technically, to see how/why there is a critical point for the distribution for $T_3 | N(\tau) = 2$, one way is to setup the integral (like what's done in my answer) for the CDF as in $\Pr\{ T_3 < t ~|~N(\tau) = 2\}$. You will see that the region $\Omega$ must be split for $t < \tau$ and $t > \tau$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, conditioning on $N(1)=2$ does affect the distribution of $T_3$. The  Poisson point process to the left and right of 1 are independent. Therefore, conditionally on $N(1)=2$, $T_3$ has the same law as $[T_3 -1]+[1-T_2]$.

- on $N(1)=2$, $[T_3 -1]$ is an exponential random variable with parameter $\lambda$
- on $N(1)=2$, $[1-T_2 ]$ is 1 minus the maximum of two independent uniform random variables.